# Difference between raise(SIGABRT) and abort() methods

Tags: c++, c, posix, sigabrt

I know that both `raise(SIGABRT)` and `abort()` methods will send a SIGABRT signal to itself. But there are some difference between those 2 functions. (e.g - `abort()` function unblocks the SIGABRT signal where as `raise(SIGABRT)` does not.)

What are the other differences between `raise(SIGABRT)` and `abort()` methods

Comment: read the man page of both `raise` and `abort` syscall.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main difference it that [`abort()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html) even ends the process if `SIGABRT` is ignored.

Verbatim from [`man abort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html):

> If the **SIGABRT** signal is ignored, or caught by a handler that returns, the **abort()** function will still terminate the process.  It does this by restoring the default disposition for **SIGABRT** and then raising the signal  for  a
>          second time.